# Ruby pass method(?) as parameter?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I have a whole bunch of methods that return info from a database: lists of states, countries, languages, ethnicities, etc. for options for an application form. I know the selected ids from the form and am writing methods to get the names from the ids:

```
def state_name(state_id)
  Db.states.select{ |s| s['id'] == state_id.to_i }.first['name'] 
end

def country_name(country_id)
  Db.countries.select{ |c| c['id'] == country_id.to_i }.first['name'] 
end
```

etc.  There are a lot of them. How can I simplify with 1 method which passes in the name of the type of item (state, country, etc.) I want to get the name for, instead of repeating myself over and over again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve the problem with metaprogramming:

```
class SomeClass
  def self.define_name_method(thing, plural)
    define_method :"#{thing}_name" do |id|
      Db.send(plural).select {|x| x['id'] == id.to_i }.first['name']
    end
  end

  define_name_method :state, :states
  define_name_method :country, :countries
end

SomeClass.new.state_name(19749387) #=> "Oregon"
```

Or with a more general method:

```
class SomeClass
  def thing_name(plural, id)
    Db.send(plural).select{|x| x['id'] == id.to_i }.first['name']
  end
end

SomeClass.new.thing_name(:countries, 1239394) #=> "Estonia"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use [`Object#public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send) to call one of the methods on the current object based on the "type name" you passed as a paremeter:

```
def name(type, id)
  public_send(:"#{type}_name", id)
end

# Call like this:
name(:state, 1)
```

Or alternately, you could forgo the defniition of the `#{type}_name` methods entirely and just have your `name` method call the appropriate method on your Db object:

```
def name(type, id)
  Db.public_send(type).select{ |c| c['id'] == id.to_i }.first['name']
end

# Call like this:
name(:countries, 1)
```

Comment: I prefer this approach. By having a single method one could extract information by looping through collections; e.g., `arr = [["states", 27], ["countries", 341]].each_with_object({}) { |(s,id),h| h[[s,id]] = name(s,id) }`. That could still be done with individual methods, using `send`, but it is not as transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work, using an array of strings `%w(country state)` and use `define_method` and `.send` to dynamically create methods and call attributes on `Db`

```
%w(country state language).each do |entity|
  define_method("#{entity}_name") do |id|
    Db.send(entity.pluralize).select{ |o| o['id'] == id.to_i }.first['name']
  end
end
```

(`require 'active_support/inflector'` if not using Rails for `.pluralize`)

which dynamically creates the

```
def state_name(id)
  Db.states.select{ |o| o['id'] == id.to_i }.first['name'] 
end
```

and so on for `country_name` and `language_name`